# Showing labels for equations with eqnarray

Tags: packages, amsmath, labels

I am using `\usepackage{showlabels}` to show the labels in the pdf-file but it turns out that I only see the labels coming from `align` or `equation` environment and not the ones from `eqnarray`. Why?

I personally don't like how `align` shows the formulas that's why I use `eqnarray`. Could I still show the labels for `eqnarray` equation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `eqnarray` shouldn't be used for serious math typesetting, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Comment: Out of interest, what don't you like about the output from `align`?

Answer (score 6):

It should just work. Please always post complete documents that show the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
1&=&2\label{aa}\\
33&=&44\label{bb}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{equation}
P=NP\label{cc}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```